# Collision Detection With A Physics Object And A Non-Physics Object

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am currently working on making a little game with Corona. I am wondering how to make a collision detection with a physics object and a non-physics object in Corona. I want it to be so when the physics object touches the non-physics object an event will happen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use physics based collision detection to detect collisions with non-physics bodies.  However you can use some techniques outside of physics to see if two bodies are bumping into each other.

It requires a different way of thinking about it.  This tutorial should assist you in non-physics collision detection:

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/23/tutorial-non-physics-collision-detection/

Comment: Ok I tried what you recommend above, but I am wondering where I need to run the code. For example the hasCollided function is there, but when am I supposed to run the code. Am I supped to run it as an event listener?

Comment: You probably would want to run it on every frame. If so, you can look at this tutorial http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/02/21/understanding-coronas-enterframe-event/

Comment: +1 better than my answer, I misunderstood the question, good tutorial to know about!

Answer (score 0):

Corona uses Box2d physics engine, so you can only get collision events between objects registered with the physics module. However, a registered object can have a body type of "static" in which case it does not move, but objects of dynamic and kinematic type that collide with static physics objects will generate collision events. Take a look at [Physics Bodies](https://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-physics-bodies) and [Collisions](https://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection) and try the samples there. If you have more questions post specific questions.